# Function is returning null instead of the array object, looks very simple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two methods, spiralOrder and recurSpiral where spiralOrder is my main method. It's weird because print spiralArray, but when I return spiralArray on the next line, it returns null. I feel like I'm missing something very simple. Thanks

```
class Solution(object):
    def spiralOrder(self, matrix):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        spiralArray = []
        final = self.recurSpiral(matrix, spiralArray)
        return final

    def recurSpiral(self, matrix, spiralArray):
        print matrix
        if(len(matrix) == 0 or len(matrix[0]) == 0):
            print spiralArray
            return spiralArray

        if(len(matrix) <= 2 or len(matrix[0]) <= 2):
            self.firstThree(matrix, spiralArray)
            return spiralArray

        spiralArray = self.firstThree(matrix, spiralArray)
        print spiralArray

        notFirst = False
        for l in reversed(matrix[1:]):
            if(notFirst):
                spiralArray.append(l[0])
            else:
                notFirst = True
        print spiralArray
        self.recurSpiral(matrix[1:-1][1:-1], spiralArray)

    def firstThree(self, matrix, spiralArray):

        for i in matrix[0]:
            spiralArray.append(i)

        notFirst = False
        for j in matrix:
            if(notFirst):
                spiralArray.append(j[len(matrix[0])-1])
            else:
                notFirst = True

        notFirst = False
        for k in reversed(matrix[len(matrix)-1]):
            if(notFirst):
                spiralArray.append(k)
            else:
                notFirst = True

        print spiralArray
        return spiralArray
```

Comment: Also, you should give the parameters you are using.

Comment: @DanilSperansky It's already there, partially

Comment: Python doesn't return null. It has `None`. And that means no return statement was reached

Comment: `recurSpiral` doesn't return anything in the longest case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return statement at the end of your function. Instead of:

```
self.recurSpiral(matrix[1:-1][1:-1], spiralArray)
```

It should be:

```
return self.recurSpiral(matrix[1:-1][1:-1], spiralArray)
```

Otherwise, your function will return `None` if the end of the function is reached on that path.

Comment: Also, I see sometimes you use the return value of `firstThree` and in others you expect it to modify its 2nd argument. For the sake of clarity, always use the returned value or always expect the 2nd argument to be modified.